# Record video by from camera without mirror it like snap chat

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder, video-recording

I'm working on social mobile app. It have option to record video for profile. The issue with my recorder is that it mirror the actual video. I know it is default behaviour, but want it work like sanpchat.

**Preview**

[image: Video when preview]

**After recording and playback**

[image: After recording and playback]

Here is my code

```
// return camera instance when activity open first time
private Camera getCameraInstance() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    releaseCamera();
    releaseMediaRecorder();
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
        if (cameraId < 0) {
            cameraId = findBackFacingCamera();
        }
        c = Camera.open(cameraId);

        // setCameraDisplayOrientation(this,cameraId,c);
        //setCameraDisplayOrientation(this, cameraId, c);
        c.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}
// return __cameraPreview Id 1 to open front camera
private int findFrontFacingCamera() { 
    int cameraId = -1;
    // Search for the front facing camera
    int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            cameraId = i;
            setOrientationHint = 270 ;
            cameraFront = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return cameraId;
}
// prepare and start recording
private boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    try {
        myCamera.unlock();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaRecorder.setCamera(myCamera);

    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    //mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

    if (cameraPreview.getVideoSize() != null) {
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(saveUrl);

        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000000);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(cameraPreview.getVideoSize().width, cameraPreview.getVideoSize().height);

        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    } else {
        CamcorderProfile cp = CamcorderProfile.get(cameraId, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
        mediaRecorder.setProfile(cp);
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "Video profile CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH: " + "cp.quality:" + cp.quality
            + ", cp.videoFrameWidth:" + cp.videoFrameWidth
            + ", cp.videoFrameHeight:" + cp.videoFrameHeight);

    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(MAX_VIDEO_LENGTH);
    mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(setOrientationHint);
    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();

    } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    mediaRecorder.start();
    return true;
}
```

I want it should be same as preview in playback. Sanpchat is already doing the same, thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `cameraPreview`?

Comment: it is subclass of
 `SurfaceView`

Comment: use `TextureView` and `setTransform(Matrix transform)`

Comment: it will change the preview, will it also change the recorded video?

Comment: it is for preview only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing work for me finally i need to do it on api side where i submit the video. After upload video i use `ffmpeg` to vertical flip it and set angle in metadata. here is the command for this.

```
ffmpeg -i VIDEO_PATH -vf "vflip" -metadata:s:v rotate=180 DEST_PATH
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm really stucked in this issue . I didn't find a way to flip a video

Comment: This ffmpeg operator is taking too much time to be processed, have you figured out any other solution ?

Answer (score 3):

You have set the orientation for the Front facing camera to 270 here,

```
setOrientationHint = 270 ;
```

Instead I would suggest to set the orientation to 180 degree like below,

```
setOrientationHint = (info.orientation - 180 + 360) % 360;
```

This will also change the entire video file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a TextureView, documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) and apply a transform of -1 scale on the X axis, function [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html#setTransform%28android.graphics.Matrix%29)

Comment: Whilst this is correct, link only answers are [not considered good practise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/why-is-linking-bad) on Stack Overflow. The question "answer" should actually contain an answer or at very least a summary of the content and how it pertains to the question.

Comment: I apologise for it, I thought it was correct since the links contain code easy to understand.

Comment: it will change the preview, will it also change the recorded video?

Comment: Hi, I tried the scaling transform as suggested by you and in many other SO threads but that only affects the preview and not the video written to file. Do you know of any other solutions?